# Second order sql injection in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
public static boolean jdbcExecute(String query,Statement pstmt, String engineName){
     boolean res = false;
    int dbType = ServerProperty.getReference().getDBType(engineName);
    PreparedStatement pstmtNew = null;
     if(pstmt instanceof PreparedStatement){
            pstmtNew = (PreparedStatement)pstmt;
            res = pstmtNew.execute();    // Second order sql injection
        }else{
            res = pstmt.execute(WFSUtil.TO_STRING(query, false, dbType)); // No second order sql injection 
        }
       return res;
    }
```

Why second order sql injection is occuring at this place?

Comment: Since you don't show how `pstmt` is produced, it is impossible to say.

Comment: You may have a second order SQL injection here, if the query `pstmt` was created with was, for example, created using concatenation with some values in the database. See:  http://download.oracle.com/oll/tutorials/SQLInjection/html/lesson1/les01_tm_attacks2.htm

Comment: pstmt is passed into jdbcExecute() from another method like this..      pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from tableName");

Comment: This does not answer how `pstmt` is created. How do you know that you have second order SQL injection vulnerability there?

Comment: Using Checkmarx ..

Comment: Only looking at this piece of code, there's no way to say whether there may or may not be a vulnerability there. Merely executing a prepared statement does not constitute second order SQL injection per se.

Comment: What extra you need, pls tell...

Comment: See above - we'd need to see how `pstmt` is constructed.

Comment: I solve this by extracting query from pstmtNew then sanitized that query using WFSUtil method and second order sql injection gone.